# Load objects in Hector with their Indexes

Tags: java, indexing, cassandra, hector

Is there any way to load Object with indexes in column instead of key in Hector(Cassandra Client)?

I used to do this by finding its key using *RangeSliceQuery* and then load it with
`public <T,I> T load(Class<T> clazz,I id)`

is there any better way?
thanks,